# Java: How do I set a maximum length for a Double?

Tags: java, string, double

How do I set a maximum length for a double?

```
double divSum = number1 / number2;  
String divDisplay = number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + divSum + " "; 

JLabel divSumLabel= new JLabel();
divSumLabel.setText(divDisplay)
```

How do I set the maximum lenght for `divSum`?

`1 / 3 =` `0.333333...` How do I set the maximum lenght, so its only `0.333`?

*I could do:*
`int maxLenght = 3;`

```
String stringDivSum = String.valueOf(divSum);
String shortDivSum = null; 
if(stringDivSum.length() > maxLenght){
    shortDivSum = stringDivSum.substring(0, maxLenght);
}
```

`String divDisplay = number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + shortDivSum + " ";`
But when I then do `1 / 3` it prints out `1 / 3 =` `0.3`?

Comment: Make use of String.out.printf() statements!

Comment: You can try like this `DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
  String formate = df.format(amount); `

Comment: Do you want to store `0.333` or only print it?

Comment: do you mean the length of the precision?

Comment: You cannot change the precision of `double`, but you can change how many digits are _displayed_ in the presentation of the number.

Comment: Use `stringDivSum.substring(0,stringDivSum.indexOf('.')+maxLenght+1);`. since you want decimal upto 3 digit so you should count after dot(.) onwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `String.format(...)`

[String.format()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format-java)

```
double divSum = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.3f",(double)number1  /  number2)) ;
```

**Precision, double.**

> We can specify the precision of a double or float. We use the "f" to
>   indicate a floating-point. Before this we specify ".3" to mean "three
>   numbers after the decimal."

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked for me! :) But could you maybe explain the code for me? I'm new to Java...

Comment: Sorry, ignore my first comment... I forgot to change something in the code... My bad. You code works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
double dblValue2 = Math.round( .333333 * 1000.0 ) / 1000.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
String.format("%.2f", (double)value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
System.out.format("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f",number1,number2,divsum)
```

You basically tell the formatter to expect 3 floats with 2 decimals with `%.2f`. It is important to supply the variables in order you want them to, so writing `,number1,number2,divsum` will yield different results than writing `,number2,number1,divsum` If you want to print int, short or long, you use `%d`. If you want to print string you use `%s`. But you can also google that.

Also, storing numeric data in String in case of mathematical operations is kind of pointless exercise and only bloats your code.

Comment: I just edited my question. I want to use the String for a `JLabel`

Comment: Why redirect towards Google when [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) is pretty clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the result of the division with a scale of 3 (i.e. 3 digits after the decimal point), you need to use a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this. This class allows to do arbitrary-precision calculus on decimal values.

```
int number1 = 1, number2 = 3;
BigDecimal divSum = BigDecimal.valueOf(number1).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(number2), 3, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

The [`divide(divisor, scale, roundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-int-) function of `BigDecimal` can take a scale (here set to 3) and a rounding mode (here set to [`DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN), this rounding mode truncates after the scale has been reached, which is what we want here). This will perform the division and the result will be rounded down with a scale of 3.

You can then print the result with:

```
String divDisplay = number1 + " / " + number2 + " = " + divSum + " ";
System.out.println(divDisplay); // prints "1 / 3 = 0.333"
```